# Getting driving distance via google map using Android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the driving distance between two points by passing source and destination's latitude and longitude.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText t1,t2,t3,t4;
    TextView v1,v2;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2);
        t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t3);
        t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t4);
        v1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.v1);
        v2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.v2);

        t1.getText().toString();
        t2.getText().toString();
        t3.getText().toString();
        t4.getText().toString();

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + t1 + "," + t2 + "&destination=" + t3 + "," + t4 + "&sensor=false&units=metric"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.example.john.bt2");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.john.bt2.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/t1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/t2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/t3" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/v1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now when i click the button, the app crashes. I know I am missing something in my code. Maybe JSON part... However i don't know how to add it. It would be very helpful if you explain the code you suggest as i am new to Android. Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my logcat

```
04-02 07:53:34.320 24514-24514/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-02 07:53:34.424 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.john.bt2, real application class is null.
04-02 07:53:34.424 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
04-02 07:53:34.448 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
04-02 07:53:34.456 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16104: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
04-02 07:53:34.456 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.456 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
04-02 07:53:34.456 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
04-02 07:53:34.456 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16106: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16110: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 690: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-02 07:53:34.460 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.464 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-02 07:53:34.464 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 712: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-02 07:53:34.464 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
04-02 07:53:34.628 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
04-02 07:53:34.628 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16538: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
04-02 07:53:34.628 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 422: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 653: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 655: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-02 07:53:34.644 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-02 07:53:34.652 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
04-02 07:53:34.656 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 151 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
04-02 07:53:34.656 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
04-02 07:53:35.080 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so

                                                              [ 04-02 07:53:35.084 24514:24514 D/         ]
                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb82b9a28, tid 24514
04-02 07:53:35.124 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-02 07:53:35.124 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-02 07:53:35.180 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 294K, 11% free 3061K/3420K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-02 07:53:35.228 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-02 07:53:35.228 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-02 07:53:35.236 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
04-02 07:53:35.240 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-02 07:53:35.240 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
04-02 07:53:35.240 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-02 07:53:37.080 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-02 07:53:37.080 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d43b20)
04-02 07:53:37.084 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.john.bt2, PID: 24514
                                                                      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.john.bt2/com.example.john.bt2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
                                                                          at com.example.john.bt2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 07:53:38.960 24514-24514/com.example.john.bt2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24514 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the exact error message from the logcat?

Comment: I have included the logcat as well.

Comment: the logcat doesn't include the error that caused the crash. Please update

Comment: Alright. I have updated it now.